# How to reset all settings to original state using Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kubuntu

I'm using kubuntu 16.04

The settings are a little messed up and I'm not able to get them back to how it looks like when you create a new account.

I would like to reset all system settings so that it looks like a newly installed kubuntu.

How can I do that?